# htmlspecialchars ignores some characters

Tags: php, utf-8, htmlspecialchars

I use `htmlspecialchars()` to escape some text, but for characters like `™` it outputs nothing. I know this is because it isn't valid `UTF-8` but how can I let `htmlspecialchars()` ignore that, store it in a database and then display the characters on a webpage?

Comment: Please enable PHP error reporting to the highest level, enable error logging, re-run your script and watch in the error log for which warnings are given.

Comment: You can pass a encoding argument to `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: I cannot reproduce that in php 5.2 - php 5.5, see http://codepad.viper-7.com/L8qu38

Comment: What is the character encoding of the input string if it is not UTF-8? And can you please provide an example line of code with the `htmlspecialchars()` call incl. all parameters you use?

Answer (score 0):

The specific flag you would use is ENT_IGNORE for what you're asking, however, the PHP docs recommend against this flag. You should be replacing it.

Take a look at the flags to determine which one you need: http://php.net/htmlspecialchars

Comment: but if I use `ENT_IGNORE` it'll just skip those characters, right? what I want is that those characters just stay as they are

Comment: @Jonan why wouldn't you want to convert them to their entity equivalents? Anyway, it seems I misread your post but for what you're asking I don't think any of the flags will ignore them - they would either discard or convert to a special character.

Comment: if I `ENT_SUBSTITUTE`, `™` will be converted to `ï¿½`. I f I use `ENT_IGNORE` it'll just be ignored

Comment: @Jonan is your encoding parameter set to UTF-8? Remember this flag will convert them to &#FFFD; so to convert them to their character entities, you will probably want to use htmlentities().

Comment: yes the encoding parameter is `UTF-8`. `htmlentities()` returns the same as `htmlspecialchars()`

Comment: @Jonan hmmm, well you must be using PHP 5.4.0+ for ENT_SUBSTITUTE to be available and I can't reproduce this in any of those versions I have access to...

Comment: Is there a way to change these non-`UTF-8` characteres to a `�`? Because I rather have that than `ï¿½`

Comment: @Jonana this could be done with htmlspecialchars/htmlentities with the ENT_SUBSTITUTE flag.

Comment: I get `ï¿½` when I use the `ENT_SUBSTITUTE` flag

Comment: @Jonan I figured, but I can't reproduce this behaviour at all on my machines.